# excel need solution: Condition should stay constant even after value changed

Tags: excel, conditional-statements

At cell A1 value is 5, B1 value is 10 and C1 condition is if(A1>B1,TRUE,FALSE)

My requirement is, if C1 value is False it should stay constant, even if i change A1 value to 15. I really appreciate if someone can help me solve this.

Comment: This is not possible without VBA, or else manually hardcoding the FALSE value into C1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, change your formula in Cell C1 to:

```
=IF(OR(A1="",B1=""),"",A1>B1)
```

Then, right click on the tab in your worksheet and select "View Code", then enter the following:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim KeyCells As Range
    Dim act As Range

    Set KeyCells = Range("A1:B1")

    If Not Application.Intersect(KeyCells, Range(Target.Address)) _
           Is Nothing Then

    If Range("C1").Value = False Then

    Set act = ActiveCell

    Range("C1").Copy
    Range("C1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Range("D1").ClearContents

    act.Select

    End If

    End If

End Sub
```